# Removal of items from list isn't working

Tags: python, list

I'm working on a pretty cool project but I need help. You see im collecting proxies from sslproxies.org, but sorting these proxies collected from the table into a list without extra info is pretty hard. So far my code isnt working. Hope u guys can help.What I want to do is delete the sixth item in a the list after every two.

```
f = open("proxies.txt", 'w+')
def getProxy():
    url = "https://www.sslproxies.org"
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
    global tlist
    tlist = []
    for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
        for td in tr.find_all('td'):
            tlist.append(td)
    clist = tlist
    count = 0
    for word in clist:
        count += 1
        if count > 2:
            clist.remove(word)
            count += 1
            if count >= 6:
                count = 0
        else:
            continue
f.write(str(clist))
```

Comment: don't remove items from a list if you are iterating forward.  see : http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/3553/common-pitfalls/12259/list-multiplication-and-common-references#t=201701031652321895116

Comment: also, your for `if count >=6` you sure that's okay?

Comment: could you be a little clearer about what you want?  Do you want to keep two items, then delete four, then keep two, then delete four, etc?

Comment: BTW thanks for replying. No i want to keep two items, then delete six, then  keep the next two and delete the six after.its all working good until                       tlist.append(td)                                                                                                   After that i cant seem to filter it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a generator that yields two items, then skips six, then yields two more, etc

```
def skip_six(l):
    for i, x in enumerate(l):
        if i%8 <= 1:
            yield x
```

You can use this to make a list like

```
clist = list(skip_six(tlist))
```

Comment: This is perfect. Sir, you are just amazing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to select first 2 columns. In this case you may want to try something like this with [pandas read html](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html). Just note that I can not access the website you mentioned. So i haven't tested this code

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_html(io ='https://www.sslproxies.org')
print df
print df[['IP Address','Port']] # select the columns that you are interested in
```